# How to place HTML elements over inline SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm able to use z-index to put various HTML elements over each other in whatever order I like, except when one of the elements in an inline SVG.  For example, given the HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Text before SVG. I'm some boring text. Such incredibly boring text. Who would possibly want to read such boring text?</p>
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="75" cy="40" r="20" fill="red" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="20" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    <p>SVG before text. I'm some boring text. Such incredibly boring text. Who would possibly want to read such boring text?</p>
</div>
```

and the matching CSS

```
p {
    width: 200px;
    z-index:10;
}
div {
    position: relative;
}
svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

no matter how I order the two or adjust the z-index, the inline SVG renders on top of the text.  How can I get the SVG behind the text?

The example above is available at https://jsfiddle.net/o0n10j78/1/ .

If it's relevant, in my actual application I'm generating nearly all of the document structure in Javascript with the assistance of jQuery, including the inline SVG and the HTML block I wish to have in front of it.

Comment: Try set the z-index of the svg to -1

Comment: That works, thank you! Now... why does it work? If you just toss your comment into an answer, I'll upvote it, and lacking a better answer I'll accept it in a few days.  However, I'd love to accept an answer that tells me _why_ it behaves this way so I can improve my mental model of the situation. I'm particularly at a loss for why it works fine for sibling, say, p's.

Comment: The problem isn't actually the svg here but the p-tag. Z-index is not applied on the elements as it doesn't have a position set. An alternative to set -1 on the svg, set position: relative on the P-tag. I didn't notice the position was missing on that one.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The z-index property is only being applied on positioned elements. Adding `position: relative;` to the paragraph tag will correctly apply it.

Look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for a full reference of the property.

On a side note: As I first wrote in a comment, setting the svg z-index to -1 works as it lowers the priority of the element below the default that all elements have. This comes with the downside that the svg actually being placed behind the div as well. Try apply a background color to the div while having the svg z-index set to -1.

Answer (score 17):

Please add a `z-index:-1` to the svg.

```
svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Better use the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `z-index: -1` as suggest by **Fazil Abdulkhadar** didn't work for me because I have a background. Therefore, my svg will be behind my background.

As suggest by **Hoshts**, I put `position: relative;` on the elements I want **in front of my absolute svg**.

For the example of this issue, it will be :

```js
p {
   position: relative; // add it
   width: 200px;
   /* z-index: 10; */ // change it to z-index: 1;
}
div {
   position: relative; // not sure it is necessary
}
svg {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   /* z-index: 1; */ // remove it
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The other solutions did not work for me as well, as I also have a background image.

Comment: You're a life saver. This was the only thing that worked. Using `z-index:1` on my SVG made the div cut off the bottom of the SVG for some reason.